# Can I create Quotes without specifying UnitAmount

Tags: xero-api

We are generating Quotes from our application using Xero API. We have created our Line Item in Poducts and Services and added price there.

From the API, we do not wish to send Price again, as this is already in Xero. We wish to send LineItem code and perhaps account (Sell vs Purchase) and let Xero use the price.

Can anyone let us know if there is a way to accomplish this, without having to query Xero for the Products and Services prices to build the Quote?

Thank you for your help.

Request:

```
{
  "Quotes": [
    {
      "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "a852a44c-3d8f-4c4b-a628-3a2c2121b9b1"
      },
      "LineItems": [
        {
          "ItemCode": "BOOK",
          "Description": "BlaBla",
          "Quantity": 1
        }
      ],
      "Date": "2022-12-20",
      "Reference": "Event Name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response (error 400):

```
{
  "ErrorNumber": 10,
  "Type": "ValidationException",
  "Message": "A validation exception occurred",
  "Elements": [
    {
      "Reference": "Event Name",
      "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "a852a44c-3d8f-4c4b-a628-3a2c2121b9b1"
      },
      "LineItems": [
        {
          "Description": "BlaBla",
          "ItemCode": "BOOK",
          "Quantity": 1.0
        }
      ],
      "Date": "\/Date(1671494400000)\/",
      "ValidationErrors": [
        {
          "Message": "Unit Amount cannot be empty"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do that - nothing in the documentation suggests that the unit amount field is optional, unless you're creating a line that is just a description.

Comment: Thats my observation also @droopsnoot. It just doesn't make sense to me. Thank you for checking it.